# Where is this non-multiple of 5 XP coming from?

Tags: pokemon-go

I checked my XP and realized that it is not a multiple of 5 (it currently ends in a 9). In playing the game I have noticed that all XP rewards so far have been multiples of 5, so where is this non-multiple of 5 or 10 coming from?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The non-multiple of 5 XP reward comes from training at a gym. 
Link to answered question: 
[How much xp/prestige do you gain at a gym by training?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276188/how-much-xp-prestige-do-you-gain-at-a-gym-by-training)

Answer (score 3):

Training in your own team gyms