# How have prestige gains in gym training changed now that you're allowed to use 6 Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-go

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/276188/how-much-xp-prestige-do-you-gain-at-a-gym-by-training) has not been updated since the app update where we can train with six Pokemon, so what are the exact numbers for how much prestige is gained now? It used to be 500+ for defeating a Pokemon with less CP than yours, and now it's quite a bit less, in the ballpark of 200.

Some weird stuff can happen, like what if you mostly kill a Pokemon with a powerful one of yours, then quickly switch and finish it off with a very low CP monster? Would that get more prestige than killing it with the higher one?

Comment: oh oops, sorry about that typo

Comment: don't sweat it m8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way prestige gains are calculated actually hasn't been changed since the update to training friendly gyms. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/56xd8r/psa_prestige_gain_is_calculated_based_on_the/). The formula is the same as before and based on the strongest of your 6 only. Thus, switching a weaker Pokemon in to finish off a stronger Pokemon would do nothing, since the prestige calculation only takes the highest CP Pokemon you brought into account.

Since you said that your gains went from 500+ to below 200, my guess is that you had a Pokemon in your 6 that was actually stronger than the Pokemon you defeated, which would be why you got less prestige than you were expecting.

Note: If the Pokemon you are training against are much higher level than you and are lowered to be closer to yours, then you will get generate less prestige than before, since the CP disadvantage is narrower.

Comment: So you're saying this is a duplicate?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Well, I'm not sure it's a duplicate, since it's really asking about whether there was a change or not, and it just turns out that there hasn't been... Would that be a duplicate?

Comment: In my eyes, absolutely.

Comment: Training against one Pokemon with the same Pokemon of yours before and after the update results in different prestige gains, so _something_ had to have changed. If you think altered calculation is a duplicate, then ok...

Comment: Not a duplicate - there _has_ been a change; that you can now use 6 Pokemon and it's the CP of your highest 6 that is taken into account is the answer to this question, but not the other, older one.